# Git doesn't ignore "nbproject" directory

Tags: git, netbeans-8

When I `git push` my project, it doesn't ignore the "nbproject" directory although it's in the ".gitignore" file!

I tried :

```
git rm -r --cached nbproject
```

it stops tracking 'nbproject' in the next git push only, but it will be pushed again from the second push !!

Why does this happen ??!

Comment: What do you mean by "does not ignore"? `git push` does not look at the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: @j6t I mean that the "nbproject" directory was pushed to the git repo although it shouldn't be pushed as I put it in the ".gitignore" file

Comment: @1615903  No, I don't ask about that. I tried to make this and it remove "nbproject" from the repo, but it's pushed again on the next git push !

Answer (score 4):

Use `git rm -r --cached nbproject/` to stop tracking `nbproject` from the next commit (without deleting it).

`.gitignore` will not work on files that are already being tracked.

Comment: I tried this .. it stops tracking 'nbproject' in the next git push only, but it will be pushed again from the second push !!